# How to undo `git annex initremote`

Tags: git, git-annex

I used

```
git annex initremote myrsync type=rsync rsyncurl=ssh://... encryption=none
```

to initialise a remote. However, when attempting a `git annex copy`, I get errors like:

```
  rsync failed -- run git annex again to resume file transfer
failed
copy ... (checking myrsync...) (to myrsync...) 
ssh: Could not resolve hostname ssh: Name or service not known
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.0]
```

I'd like to undo the `initremote` so I could try again. I found I could comment out the `[remote "myrsync"]` entry in .git/config but I am not sure if this is the safe/correct way of doing things.

Comment: This *may* help you: https://git-annex.branchable.com/forum/How_to_delete_a_remote__63__/

Comment: Hmm, didn't seem to help. I thought there might be something special for repos that had never been used.